# JSON data is not loaded when using ngInfiniteScroll?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use infinite data scroll on my page so I am using ngInfinite scroll but whenever I run my file something goes wrong and data is not loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Infifnite scroll</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  
   
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngInfiniteScroll/1.2.1/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='DemoController'>
  <div infinite-scroll='reddit.nextPage()' infinite-scroll-disabled='reddit.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
    <div ng-repeat='item in reddit.items'>
      <span class='score'>{{item.score}}</span>
      <span class='title'>
        <a ng-href='{{item.url}}' target='_blank'>{{item.title}}</a>
      </span>
      <small>by {{item.author}} -
        <a ng-href='http://reddit.com{{item.permalink}}' target='_blank'>{{item.num_comments}} comments</a>
      </small>
      <div style='clear: both;'></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show='reddit.busy'>Loading data...</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script>
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);

myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope, Reddit) {
  $scope.reddit = new Reddit();
});

// Reddit constructor function to encapsulate HTTP and pagination logic
myApp.factory('Reddit', function($http) {
  var Reddit = function() {
    this.items = [];
    this.busy = false;
    this.after = '';
  };

  Reddit.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    if (this.busy) return;
    this.busy = true;

    var url = "http://api.reddit.com/hot?after=" + this.after + "&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";
    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
      var items = data.data.children;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        this.items.push(items[i].data);
      }
      this.after = "t3_" + this.items[this.items.length - 1].id;
      this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));
  };

  return Reddit;
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo code I am working on, may be I am doing some mistake, Please help me with my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's working fine? New data is added..

Comment: nops it's not working according to me as get request is not completed and no data is loaded for the scroll

Comment: So the snippet you provided is not an actual representation of the issue? Because the snippet seems to be working.

Comment: oh will check that. Thanks :)

Comment: Old post, I know, but I wanted to add my 2 cents anyway.

What browser are you using to test this? I notice it works in Firefox (Quantum 59.0.2) but not in Chrome (64.0.3282.186).

Read [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-my-Angular-js-website-work-on-Chrome-when-it-works-on-Firefox) for a clearer, albeit unofficial understanding of why this works